# 503 error in browser on fetch despite nginx logging 200 success status

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Within my app, there's some fetch requests to the server that work without issue for almost all users. There's no problem within the server in responding, and I've watched the logs live, and it returns a 200 status and the expected data 100% of the time.

For a small number of users, once the size of the response goes above 30kb, in the browser the request fails with a 503 / forbidden error message. This is despite the request being handled correctly within our server, and all logs saying it was fine.

My theory is that these users must be within a corporate network that is somehow intercepting / blocking requests over that threshold. 2 of the users we have confirmed with (and watched them live over teams) are in the same corporate network. I don't know about other users.

Is this possible? Or could there be other explanations?

Comment: [503 is "Service Unavailable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code), not "forbidden". Maybe the server is overloaded ? Maybe some hard drive is full (and might be cleaned up automatically), or too many requests are happening ?